# Merge two arrays with condition on key values in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am new to python. I was just trying to do some things to get to know python.

What I am now trying to do is merge two arrays of same size. The condition is that if key is a specific value(`nk` in my case) then value should be appended to the previous key or current key.

below is the code I wrote to do it and its working. I'm sure that I have written a very bad code(beginner :) )

Below code has two arrays. keys and values. What I am trying to do is, if the value in key is `nk` then that particular element in values array is appended to a list with the key previously obtained.

```
import json


keys = ["one", "nk", "nk", "two", "nk", "three", "nk", "four", "nk"]
values = ["quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "on", "lazy", "dog", "asfdsagfds", "sdfgre"]
mydict = []
key = "head"
val = []

for i in range(0, len(keys)):
    if(keys[i] != "nk") :
        mydict.append({key:val})
        key = ""
        val = []
        key = keys[i]
        val.append(values[i])
    else :
        val.append(values[i])

    if(i == len(keys)-1) :
        mydict.append({key:val})

print(json.dumps(mydict, indent=4))
```

Output :

```
[
    {
        "head": []
    },
    {
        "one": [
            "quick",
            "brown",
            "fox"
        ]
    },
    {
        "two": [
            "jumps",
            "on"
        ]
    },
    {
        "three": [
            "lazy",
            "dog"
        ]
    },
    {
        "four": [
            "asfdsagfds",
            "sdfgre"
        ]
    }
]
```

Now the question is is there any easy way of doing this using any python inbuilt functions?

Comment: reason for -1 will help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not bad at all. There are no builtin functions solving this particular problem, but you can use `zip()` to iterate over two lists in parallel. Using `zip()` combined with the fact that dicts contain references to objects, not copies, allows you to write the code without keeping track of array indices:

```
keys = ["one", "nk", "nk", "two", "nk", "three", "nk", "four", "nk"]
values = ["quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "on", "lazy", "dog", "asfdsagfds", "sdfgre"]
key = "head"
acc = {key: []}
mydict = []

for new_key, value in zip(keys, values):

    if(new_key != "nk") :
        acc = {new_key: []}
        mydict.append(acc)
        key = new_key

    acc[key].append(value)

print(json.dumps(mydict, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python you can use the `zip` function to iterate over two lists at the same time, and you can :

```
keys = ["one", "nk", "nk", "two", "nk", "three", "nk", "four", "nk"]
values = ["quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "on", "lazy", "dog", "asfdsagfds", "sdfgre"]
container = []
my_dict = []
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    if k != "nk":
        container = []
        my_dict.append({k: container})
    container.append(v)
```

Generally speaking, using indexes to iterate over lists is considered "un-Pythonic".

Comment: `Generally speaking, using indexes to iterate over lists is considered "un-Pythonic".` Thanks I will consider it :)